# Using Monte Carlo method to perturb Matrix elements about 10% around their nominal values

Tags: matlab, matrix, montecarlo

Matrix A with size 9*9 is available here.

```
A = [-6.932e-2,17.41,-36.75,0,0,0,-6.0660,-31.54,0;
    -1.435e-4,2.719e-2,-1.411e-3,3.467e-1,0,-9.380e-1,7.139e-2,-1.691e-2,0;
    -4.537e-4,1.870e-3,-2.025e-1,0,1,0,-4.688e-2,7.563e-3,0;
    -1.304e-4,-7.179,-4.916e-1,-6.172e-1,-3.689e-2,7.631e-1,0,0,0;
    2.297e-5,0,-8.667e-1,4.393e-2,-1.947e-1,-2.026e-2,0,0,0;
    1.964e-5,4.263e-2,-1.329e-2,1.233e-3,1.579e-2,-1.600e-1,0,0,0;
    0,0,0,1,1.941e-1,2.771e-1,0,6.258e-2,0;
    0,0,0,0,8.192e-1,-5.736e-1,-5.612e-2,0,0;
    0,0,0,0,6.055e-1,8.648e-1,0,2.006e-2,0]
```

How can we perturb elements of matrix A around their nominal values about n% and get perturb model for matrix A?

Comment: As I understand you want randomly create matrix A elements around n% of their nominal values and create n model of A.Am I right?If yes you can use MonteCarlo method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a matrix with all of the perturbed values will be faster than going element-wise.  This example uses a uniform distribution, though it can be easily altered for a normal distribution.

```
N = 20;
d = 0.1;

A_perturb =  repmat(A,[1 1 N]) + repmat(A,[1 1 N]) .* ...
    ((rand(size(A,1),size(A,2),N) - 0.5) .* 2 .* d);
```

To get all of the values for A(1,1):

```
>> reshape(A_perturb(1,1,:),[],1)

ans =

-0.0702
-0.0762
-0.0627
-0.0628
-0.0632
-0.0739
-0.0722
-0.0705
-0.0637
-0.0746
-0.0759
-0.0702
-0.0715
-0.0685
-0.0645
-0.0631
-0.0711
-0.0660
-0.0672
-0.0706
```

To get A for the ninth iteration:

```
>> A_perturb(:,:,9)

ans =

-0.0637   16.8216  -37.8357         0         0         0   -5.8413  -30.0970         0
-0.0001    0.0275   -0.0015    0.3390         0   -0.9977    0.0713   -0.0153         0
-0.0005    0.0017   -0.1889         0    1.0960         0   -0.0427    0.0081         0
-0.0001   -6.7782   -0.5080   -0.6484   -0.0387    0.7986         0         0         0
0.0000         0   -0.8465    0.0413   -0.2107   -0.0210         0         0         0
0.0000    0.0408   -0.0138    0.0013    0.0161   -0.1751         0         0         0
0         0         0    1.0582    0.1925    0.2722         0    0.0630         0
0         0         0         0    0.7448   -0.5221   -0.0575         0         0
0         0         0         0    0.6176    0.8328         0    0.0212         0
```

Comment: 10% variation implies a uniform distribution.  A normal distribution will bunch the values around the mean much closer than 10%.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this method to create n model of matrix `A`.

For each elements of your matrix do the following.  For example by selecting of your matrix `A(1,1)=-6.932e-2`.

```
n = 20; % The number of elements evaluations
sd = 0.01;  % The percent of perturbation around nominal value
A_11 = (randn(n,1)*sd*A(1,1))+A(1,1);

.... .
```

... and you will get A_11 as:

```
   -0.0692
   -0.0692
   -0.0695
   -0.0695
   -0.0687
   -0.0693
   -0.0692
   -0.0698
   -0.0701
   -0.0701
   -0.0687
   -0.0694
   -0.0685
   -0.0685
   -0.0693
   -0.0704
   -0.0688
   -0.0696
   -0.0692
   -0.0701
```

You should do this for other elements of your matrix.

By selecting `n = 20`, you can obtain 20 elements for matrix `A(1,1)` and if you did this for other elements, you can reach n model for matrix `A`.